# Simple Tests in Django failed

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to do simple tests in Django (v. 2.0.5). Since I can not see why I'm getting the '404 != 200' error, I post all relevant data.

**`test.py`**

```
from django.urls import resolve, reverse
from django.test import TestCase
from .views import home, board_topics
from .models import Board


class HomeTests(TestCase):
    def test_home_view_status_code(self):
        url = reverse('home')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_home_url_resolves_home_view(self):
        view = resolve('/home/')
        self.assertEqual(view.func, home)


class BoardTopicsTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Board.objects.create(name='Django', description='Django discussion board')

    def test_board_topics_view_success_status_code(self):
        url = reverse('board_topics', kwargs={'pk': 1})
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_board_topics_view_not_found_status_code(self):
        url = reverse('board_topics', kwargs={'pk': 99})
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)

    def test_board_topics_url_resolves_board_topics_view(self):
        view = resolve('/boards/1/')
        self.assertEqual(view.func, board_topics)
```

**`urls.py`**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from boards import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('boards/<int:pk>/', views.board_topics, name='board_topics'),
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**`views.py`**

```
...
def board_topics(request, pk):
    try:
        board = Board.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Board.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return render(request, 'topics.html', {'board': board})
```

**`Traceback`**

```
FAIL: test_board_topics_view_success_status_code (boards.tests.BoardTopicsTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/.../boards/tests.py", line 25, in test_board_topics_view_success_status_code
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    AssertionError: 404 != 200
```

I wonder why I'm getting this error because I can call the views and I also get a 404 error when I try to call a page that does not exist (except Board.DoesNotExist). Is there a way to make the tests different (easier)? Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: `Board.objects.get(pk=1)` leads to `Board.DoesNotExist` - did you create some fixtures/test data in the DB specified for tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to adjust your test to automatically pickup the ID of the created object.

```
class BoardTopicsTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.board = Board.objects.create(name='Django', description='Django discussion board')

    def test_board_topics_view_success_status_code(self):
        url = reverse('board_topics', kwargs={'pk': self.board.id})
```

Maybe the database is not properly cleared between the tests?

Answer (score 0):

Use `resolve('/')` instead of `resolve('/home/')`

```
def test_home_url_resolves_home_view(self):
    view = resolve('/')
    self.assertEquals(view.func, home)
```